# how to prevent text scaling out site the image object using fabric js

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fabricjs

How to prevent object scale out side image object(if user will select any text object over the image then user is not able to scale this text object outside of the image so ) so i want solution for it. example show in screen shot.
Now object scaling prevent canvas boundary.

image URl = http://nncdev.com/labelmaker/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: The screenshot appears to be missing

Comment: sorry for that i have added image URL please check @wayne phipps

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z4dcvt1h/1/ please check fiddle how to prevent text out side rect @John M

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to only restrict the width/height of the text or also its position? In your screenshot, the text is seen outside the red box - is this expected or something you want to avoid?

Comment: restrict only height and width of object means object not scale out side of red box.you can see  example in jsfiddle.net/z4dcvt1h/1.